# canOpenURL Google maps issue

Tags: swift, google-maps

so today we received a ticket that our application does't open de Google Maps but open another app **JabJobs** in our application we check if there is **GoogleMaps** installed as follow:

```
(UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string:"comgooglemaps://")! as URL))
```

so if there is an GoogleMaps installed there is no problem but if we **uninstall** the **GoogleMaps** app, and install **JabJobs** the `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL` still return **true** value and when we go further with

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string:
                "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(place.lat),\(place.lng)&directionsmode=driving")! as URL)
```

a system popUp is displayed with **"MyApp" wants to open "JabJobs"**

- Q1. Is that possible that another app to respond to same URL as googleApp ?
- Q2. How can i check if there is a GoogleMaps installed if the code above doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Of course it's possible, you can respond to any URL scheme if you register app for it.
2. From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme, I can see that Google Maps have more url schemes, for example `comgooglemapsurl://`. You can check if these 2 schemes are available if not then it's probably other App, unless they support all these schemes... then you can't do nothing, but as I can see `JabJobs` does not support `comgooglemapsurl://` scheme.